# Seeking commercial off-the-shelf GIS server products that work on Linux

Tags: software-recommendations, server

I am looking for a suitable COTS GIS server product for Linux platform.  The product should allow 500 Clients concurrently and should have Java / C++ development APIs.
So far I found Esri ArcGIS Server which supports Linux.  I need a few more products which have good performance like Esri.

Can you share the list of  available COTS (Commercial off the shelf) GIS server products?

Answer (score 6):

These are my two favorite which run on linux. I believe they do meet your requirements.

**Even though they are free, you can pay for support. "linux is free if your time is worthless"** (for "free" as in cost - "free" as in freedom isn't about money...

[image: Geoserver]

## http://geoserver.org

---

[image: MapServer]

## http://mapserver.org/

There are also "products" built out of these, such as the [OpenGeo Suite](http://opengeo.org/products/suite/)

Answer (score 4):

**ArcGIS Server (Linux)** 10.1

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/install-guides/arcgis-server-unix/10.1/index.html#//00sz00000012000000

ESRI has greatly improved it install process of ArcGIS Server on Linux

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/install-guides/arcgis-server-unix/10.1/index.html#/What_s_new_in_ArcGIS_10_1_for_Server_install/00sz00000012000000/

Service Pack 1 notes:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/install-guides/arcgis-server-unix/10.1/index.html#/About_ArcGIS_10_1_SP1_for_Server/00sz0000002z000000/

**FME Server 2012/13 [Recommended]**

http://www.safe.com/fme/fme-technology/fme-server/tech-specs/

**gisvm** Server

http://gisvm.com/download.html

**GIS Server**
http://www.gisinfo.net/products/gisserver.htm